Python type hints for class decorators with self references
My ultimate goal is to write a system to easily record function calls (in particular for class methods).
I started by writing a class Loggable with a wrapper method that allows me to decorate subclasses methods and record their calls
Param = ParamSpec("Param")
RetType = TypeVar("RetType")


CountType = TypeVar("CountType", bound="FunctionCount")


class FunctionCount(Generic[CountType]):
    def __init__(self, count_dict: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        self.count_dict = count_dict

    @staticmethod
    def count(
        func: Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType],
    ) -> Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType]:
        def wrapper(
            self: CountType, *args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs
        ) -> RetType:
            function_name = f"{self.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}"
            if function_name not in self.count_dict:
                self.count_dict[function_name] = 0
            self.count_dict[function_name] += 1

            return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

Now I can write subclasses and record their calls:
class A(FunctionCount):
    def __init__(self, count_dict: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        super().__init__(count_dict)

    @FunctionCount.count
    def func(self) -> None:
        pass

    @FunctionCount.count
    def func2(self) -> None:
        pass


count_dict: dict[str, int] = {}

a = A(count_dict)

a.func()
a.func()
a.func2()

print(count_dict)
assert count_dict == {"A.func": 2, "A.func2": 1}

It works really well and I was glad.
But then I thought it would be nice to have custom names for the methods so I changed the wrapper into a decorator
class FunctionCount(Generic[CountType]):
    def __init__(self, count_dict: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        self.count_dict = count_dict

    @staticmethod
    def count(
        f_name: str | None = None,
    ) -> Callable[
        [Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType]],
        Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType],
    ]:
        def decorator(
            func: Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType],
        ) -> Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType]:
            def wrapper(
                self: CountType, *args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs
            ) -> RetType:
                function_name = f_name or f"{self.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}"
                if function_name not in self.count_dict:
                    self.count_dict[function_name] = 0
                self.count_dict[function_name] += 1

                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

            return wrapper

        return decorator

Then I just had to change the decorator calls
class A(FunctionCount):
    def __init__(self, count_dict: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        super().__init__(count_dict)

    @FunctionCount.count()
    def func(self) -> None:
        pass

    @FunctionCount.count("custom_name")
    def func2(self) -> None:
        pass

a.func()
a.func()
a.func2()

print(count_dict)
assert count_dict == {"A.func": 2, "custom_name": 1}

This scripts also works very well but now mypy is giving me hard times.
When I call the a.func method, I get the following mypy error:
Invalid self argument "A" to attribute function "func" with type "Callable[[Never], None]" mypy(misc)
I guess using a decorator instead of a wrapper caused this error but I can't understand why and what should I do to correct it.
Does someone know how to have a correctly typed decorator this way ?

Your class shouldn't be generic in CountType - count method is generic by design, but not the class itself. Also, I highly recommend running mypy --strict - it would have pointed to other problems in your code causing Never inference. https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=af317b7ca241fd37490179134bf9c037

Also look at defaultdict to simplify wrapper body, as well as Self from typing to avoid CountType altogether. Additionally, the clue that your class shouldn't be generic is the fact that the generic parameter is used nowhere in __init__.

@MarioIshac could you show the way with Self? You can't use Self in staticmethods, and in a classmethod it will be wrong (always resolved to FunctionCount, not to the class where you call .count).

(and there's also dict.setdefault method for such simple cases, if you don't want to change public interface this way)

@STerliakov https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&flags=strict&gist=cfebe3bdcdfcbe9553690600d1767b89, though mypy forces use of A.count due to the issue you mentioned. However, OP's design looks brittle since creating two instances of FunctionCount will overwrite count_dict. Since the state is being initialized external to the class anyway, I believe removing the class entirely is the best approach here.

Never mind, I just realized that mypy actually has a bug in accepting the above code. It fails under pyright and at Python runtime due to referencing A within A. Apologies, so you are correct Self is not usable here.

I think this should indeed be an answer instead of a comment.
Your class shouldn't be generic in CountType - count method is generic by design, but not the class itself. You try to spell "a staticmethod that works on some callable with first argument being a subtype of FunctionCount", not "a class that can only apply its staticmethod to a callable with...", right? Then it's the staticmethod itself what should be generic, not the class! Compare with the following:
from typing import ParamSpec, Callable, TypeVar, Concatenate

Param = ParamSpec("Param")
RetType = TypeVar("RetType")
CountType = TypeVar("CountType", bound="FunctionCount")

class FunctionCount:
    def __init__(self, count_dict: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        self.count_dict = count_dict

    @staticmethod
    def count(
        f_name: str | None = None,
    ) -> Callable[
        [Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType]],
        Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType],
    ]:
        def decorator(
            func: Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType],
        ) -> Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType]:
            def wrapper(
                self: CountType, /, *args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs
            ) -> RetType:
                function_name = f_name or f"{self.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}"
                if function_name not in self.count_dict:
                    self.count_dict[function_name] = 0
                self.count_dict[function_name] += 1

                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

            return wrapper
            
        return decorator

This passes mypy --strict (mypy playground, pyright playground).
As an aside, run mypy --strict when you encounter some mypy errors that contain Never (or just something "weird" you struggle to understand) - that may point out other places where you're doing something mypy does not like. mypy --strict produces a bunch of errors on your original code, one of the most important ones is about missing generic argument for the subclass (see here).

Thank you it worked !
I saw this Generic mechanic in another stackoverflow post but I assume it does not apply in my case !
I also had another error due to the fact that self was not positional only so I fixed it

mypy has problems because the type vars and param specs are only present in the return annotation (and not in the arguments). Unfortunately, I don't know a way to make it work for every edge case, especially if you are annotating (instance or class) methods with it. But for regular functions (at least it worked for most of my use cases) it might work to create a generic decorator protocol and set that as return type for your decorator - similar to this:
class Decorator(Protocol, Generic[CountType, Param, RetType]):
    __call__(self, __self__: CountType, *args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs) -> RetType:
        ...


class FunctionCount(Generic[CountType]):
    def __init__(self, count_dict: dict[str, int]) -> None:
        self.count_dict = count_dict

    @staticmethod
    def count(
        f_name: str | None = None,
    ) -> Decorator[CountType, Param, RetType]:
        def decorator(
            func: Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType],
        ) -> Callable[Concatenate[CountType, Param], RetType]:
            def wrapper(
                self: CountType, *args: Param.args, **kwargs: Param.kwargs
            ) -> RetType:
                function_name = f_name or f"{self.__class__.__name__}.{func.__name__}"
                if function_name not in self.count_dict:
                    self.count_dict[function_name] = 0
                self.count_dict[function_name] += 1

                return func(self, *args, **kwargs)

            return wrapper

        return decorator


I don't understand why the __self__ parameter.
Is it because it is supposed to be applied to methods ?

I just wrote your desired signature. The __call__ function always has self as first parameter but the methods you want to decorate, too. So you need that as extra argument. But I didn't test it. Does it work for you?

Well I get errors about Param and RetType being invariant instead of covariant

also the decorator you return seems not to be compatible with your protocol Decorator since it takes a Callable as input and returns one as output while your Protocol takes the function arguments and returns RetType
